# Handle complex object in Reducer

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a complex data similar to what I've given below.

```
const initialState = {
    medicationschedule: [
        {
            date: '2019-08-27',
            medications: [
                {
                    title: '8.00 AM', 
                    id:'1111',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item2', isTaken: 4,mg: '2000 mg',capsules:'teaspoon'}
                ]},
                {
                    title: '12.03 PM', 
                    id:'11112',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item3', isTaken: 2,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item4', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
                ]},
                {
                    title: '3.30 PM', 
                    id:'11113',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 3,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
                ]},
            ]
        },
        {
            date: '2019-08-26',
            medications: [
                {
                    title: '8.00 AM', 
                    id:'11151',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item2', isTaken: 4,mg: '2000 mg',capsules:'teaspoon'}
                ]},
            ]
        }
    ],
    selectedDate: Date()
};
```

Now I have to update the `isTaken` status inside the medication array. I get sufficient data to my reducer (dateString, idOfMedication, nameOfMedication). But I had to keep on looping inside array after array.

my reducer

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_DATE:
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {...state, selectedDate: action.payload}
        case CHANGE_MEDICATION_TAKEN_STATUS:
            console.log(action.date +" "+ action.id +" "+ action.name +" "+ action.takenStatus)
            return state;

    }

    return state;
};
```

how I should go about changing this status inside the reducer. Can someone help me out.

Comment: AFAIK, Reducer doest provide such methods, It's your application logic to manipulate the state and reducer will return the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the schedule by date and inside the schedule find the item by id:

```
case CHANGE_MEDICATION_TAKEN_STATUS:
  const schedule = state.medicationschedule.map(schedule => {
    if (schedule.date === action.date) {
      schedule = {
        ...schedule,
        medications: schedule.medications.map(medication => {
          if (medication.id === action.id) {
            medication = {
              ...medication,
              isTaken: action.takenStatus
            }
          }
          return medication
        })
      }
    }
    return schedule;
  })

return {
  ...state,
  medicationschedule: schedule
};
```